# Symfony 4 First Event

Tags: symfony, security, events, symfony4

I authenticate the user with `ROLE_USER` after that user open another URL need `ROLE_ADMIN` i want to add this role if the user has the role in the database.
 I'm going to use an event listener but I get access denied before `kernel.request` event execute.

Comment: Please ellaborate a bit. Your user, at time of accessing Admin page, does not have `ROLE_ADMIN`, right?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Yes I set `ROLE_ADMIN` with request event listener but I get access denied before the run the event

Comment: Your user object is serialized in session, you cannot just add the role on the fly and hope for it to work (at least, not that I am aware of). Maybe someone could correct me on this?

Comment: @JovanPerovic I create the new session in event listener and worked but the event not run before access control check.

Comment: You can add a [priority attribute](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-listener) to control the order in which the listeners are executed.  But I doubt it will help you much.  Think your basic design is flawed.  If you want a user to have ROLE_ADMIN then add it.

Comment: @Cerad Not worked. but good idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `kernel.exception` event when the `statusCode` was 403 (Access Denied) set the `ROLE_ADMIN`